# GridView Header

Tags: gridview, flutter

I want to add a fixed size header to my GridView.builder. They should scroll together. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Maybe just set NeverScrollableScrollPhysics to gridview and wrap header and grid with ListViev as an option?

Comment: CustomScrollView and use a SliverGrid instead of GridView. You can then freely add other stuff on the top of it that will scroll with it

Comment: Hi Figen, have you solved this problem?

Comment: Hi @javayhu ! I solved it with CustomScrollView and Slivers as Rémi Rousselet suggested. You can check out my repo for some examples.: https://github.com/figengungor/FlutterPlayground/tree/master/slivers For this case, check out  SliverPersistentHeader and 
SliverToBoxAdapter examples.

Comment: @FigenGüngör Thanks very much, I solved this with your method. Many thanks to Rémi Rousselet too.

Comment: You're welcome @javayhu. Glad to help=)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using plugins and would like to skip Slivers, you can consider using [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) plugin.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        crossAxisCount: 3,
        itemCount: 17,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Center(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text('$index'),
              ),
            )),
        staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
        StaggeredTile.count(index == 0 ? 3 : 1, index == 0 ? 3 : 1),
        mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
        crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]